# Django translation without request object

Tags: python, django, notifications, internationalization, translation

I'm translating my Django app, in which I have a push notification module. From that module, I send a text field to user's mobile devices. Since the trigger of those notifications is not a proper HTTP request (with its "request" object), the default Django way of translating strings doesn't work.

I have a field on every user profile with its preferred language, so I think I should write some kind of middleware which would match that field with its correct translation.

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Middleware depends on a request as well, so not sure why you think that would help. But the Django docs describe explicitly [how to set the language outside of a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`translation.override`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.override) context manager:

```
language = user.get_language()
with translation.override(language):
    # Translate your message here.
```

Comment: One thing to point, the language is only set within the `with` statement so put special attention (or don't use) [lazy translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation) inside or you may get unexpected results